# Failed to load css in JSP

Tags: css, jsp

I want to load css to my JSP in my project

here is my project structure

[image]

here is my jsp page
[image]

when I run it, the css could not load in.

Could you help me on this?

thank you

==============================================================

I tried to put css under webapp folder

[image]
and put following on the JSP

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/abc.css"/>
```

it still not loading

Comment: did you try to put the css file into the webapp folder instead of the resources folder?

Comment: No, let me try it now.

Comment: I tried, it's still failed...

Comment: please post your updated structure

Comment: I updated the structure, please help me to take a look

Comment: it should work as per your case ,You always add `type="text/css"` in the link which is necessary upto HTML 4 .  may be try `../../abc.css`

Comment: I tried... but it failed...

Comment: so please unzip your war file and check the location of your css file